# Bootstrap btn-xs does not have the same disabled style as btn

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, styles

On an application I am building, I needed to disable a button by default.
[image: The button I want to disable by default is the btn-danger]

I need the `btn-danger` to be disabled by default and I need it to be a `btn-xs` so it doesn't make the `tr` take too much space. As per the [bootstrap documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#disabled-state), for a button that is not an `<a>` tag, I added the boolean attribute `disabled` to the `button` element but I could not get the desired style.

I then realized that a `btn-xs` does not have the same style when it is disabled as a "normal" `btn` has. here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sL721onu/1/) illustrating it.

Is this behavior intended and normal? Do I need to write a css button myself? What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `btn` class as well.  So the total class list is `btn btn-xs btn-primary`.